# How to distinguish between an element and a vector of length 1 in R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to distinguish between `1` and `c(1)`? Apparently in R

```
c(1) == 1 # TRUE
as.matrix(c(1)) == 1 # TRUE
as.array(c(1)) == 1 # TRUE
```

which is a problem, for example, if I'm converting a vector to JSON:

```
library(rjson)
toJSON(c(1,2)) # "[1,2]"
toJSON(c(1)) # "1" instead of "[1]"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that with the `RJSONIO` package?  I get "[      1 ]" for both `toJSON(1)` and `toJSON(c(1))`

Comment: It's the `rjson` package. In my opinion, `toJSON(1)` should be `"1"`

Comment: `rjson::toJSON` checks the length.  i.e. it doesn't make any distinction between `c(1)` and `1`

Comment: In R `c(1)` and `1` is completely identical, so you cannot distinguish them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works as expected if you pass a list:

```
> toJSON(list(1))
[1] "[1]"
```

You can convert with `as.list`:

```
> toJSON(as.list(c(1)))
[1] "[1]"
> toJSON(as.list(c(1, 2)))
[1] "[1,2]"
```

As noted in the other answers, there is no distinction between an atomic value and a vector of length one in R -- unlike with lists, which always have a length and can contain arbitrary objects, not necessarily of the same type.

Answer (score 6):

No. As far as I know, there's no difference between `1` and `c(1)`

```
> identical(1, c(1))
[1] TRUE
```

The reason `rjson::toJSON` returns a different value for `c(1)` than it does for `c(1,2)` is because it checks the length and returns differently for length 1 objects

Answer (score 1):

In R numbers are just vectors of one entry. There is no distinction.

In fact, a one-element vector is automatically printed as if it were just a scalar:

```
a<- 1
str(a)          # num 1
b<-c(1)
str(b)          # num 1
```

If your output should encode them differently then you will have to do that manually, which you can do because your program is generating both, it knows which are "real" vectors vs. vectors that have 1 element but are *conceptually* scalar.