# R - Send json via httr::POST

Tags: r, json, post, httr

Okay so my problem was already mentionend in several other threads, but I am not able to figure it out:

I wrote the following code:

```
  my_list <- list(
    list(ids = c(100,200,300))
  )
  names(my_list) <- "Example"
  
  responseList <- httr::POST(url = url_endpoint, 
                             body = my_list, encode = "json", httr::verbose())
```

The `verbose` function shows what is sent, in this case `{"Example":{"ids":[100,200,300]}}`

In a second case I execute the following code

```
  my_list <- list(
    list(ids = c(100))
  )
  names(my_list) <- "Example"
  
  responseList <- httr::POST(url = url_endpoint, 
                             body = my_list, encode = "json", httr::verbose())
```

which leads to `{"Example":{"ids":100}}`. The important difference are the missing brackets `[]`, since `100` is seen as a single value (which it is). However the API expects those brackets and hence throws an error in this case.

I found this problem in the following thread: [How to distinguish between an element and a vector of length 1 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426510/how-to-distinguish-between-an-element-and-a-vector-of-length-1-in-r)

It seems that there is a difference between the R packages `rjson`, `RJSONIO` (and probably also `jsonlite`, which I think is used in the `httr` package - unfortunately I cannot find the source, so I might be wrong here).

Now the problem is that I do not use `toJSON` from any of these packages, but the encoding within `httr::POST`. And here the documentation states on the parameter `encode`: (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.4/topics/POST)

"For "json", parameters are automatically "unboxed" (i.e. length 1 vectors are converted to scalars). To preserve a length 1 vector as a vector, wrap in I()."

Now my question is: What exactly do I need to wrap in `I()`.?

Answer (score 0):

When finishing the question I realized its answer (at first I used `I()` within `body`):

```
  my_list <- list(
    list(ids = I(c(100)))
  )
  names(my_list) <- "Example"
  
  responseList <- httr::POST(url = url_endpoint, 
                             body = my_list, encode = "json", httr::verbose())
```